# Term to represent all possible values of a variable

Tags: variables, terminology

Is there a term to represent a set of all possible values a variable can assume?

**Analogy:**
In mathematics a domain of a function is a set of values a function is defined on (function can take as an argument).

**Examples:**

- A variable of type UInt16 can hold values in range [0-65536).
- Completion status (represented by a double value) can hold a value in range [0-100].
- Gender (represented by an Enum) can hold one of { Male, Female }.

**Q:**
What is a term to describe all possible values a variable can (contextually) assume?

Basically need a short version of "set of values for a variable". I have seen term **type** being used to describe such a range, but Type often encompasses other bits of information (e.g. a name, operations, module).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've also heard "value space" as a term for this.

Comment: Unambiguous and short. Perfect. See also: http://www.stylusstudio.com/w3c/schema2/value-space.htm

Answer (score 9):

- value set
- domain
- value range

Answer (score 3):

I would just call it the "range", or "range of values".

Comment: Range could confuse the mathematicians.

Comment: True, but when has that ever stopped us?

Answer (score 3):

Domain would be the math term.

Comment: Domain would define the set of inputs that are acceptable, but not the set of all possible values a variable can assume.

Comment: That depends.  Suppose you have, "int monkey;" The domain of int and the domain of monkey could be different.  But it's perfectly possible to say either "domain of monkey" or "domain of int."

Comment: @McWafflestix so you're saying that the set of values the variable can legally be set to ( the domain of variable.set(value) ) is different from the set of values it can assume ( the range of variable.get() )?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of programming-specific jargon with that meaning, but "domain" itself seems like a pretty good one...

[EDIT] Read the comments to this, and I actually prefer "range".

Comment: I'd disagree, assuming he was going to use this in some sort of programming context. If someone asked me "what's this variable's domain?", I wouldn't have a clue what they were trying to find out.

Comment: I didn't even think of domain. +1

Comment: I remember it in math as "domain of possible values" or something along that sort.

Comment: In fact I think I'd say range myself if I were discussing with a colleague. It's not unreasonable to consider a variable as a function, and the values are the range of that function. (It has no domain, as it has no inputs.) That's how functional programming works, after all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the exact terminology (if it even has one) but I have always referred to it as a **range** or in the case of enums **options**.

Answer (score 0):

Range is the proper term, as in "this method will return values within the range of..."; "The expected range of this variable is:..."  etc.

Comment: But the range of valid workign days for December is between 01 and 31. Yet weekends are not valid.

Comment: yes, 01 to 31 is the acceptable set of all POSSIBLE values; not necessarily all valid values for all situations (such as different years).  0 to 31 is the valid range; the solution set for any given problem does not need to include all values in the range.

Answer (score 0):

For atomic types, the type itself describes the range (e.g. int has a range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647).

Anything that is a custom type may or may not have a range because custom types (e.g. struct, class, interface) are composite types that can be made up of atomic or other custom types.

The definition of a type will also vary between different languages.

The long and short of it is generally you will only be able to apply a range to atomic types based on a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type system. In some programming laguages, a "string" can hold a sequence of characters, and an "unsigned int" can only hold positive whole numbers. In others like python, a variable can hold anything at all because it doesn't have a certain type.

Answer (score 0):

Our quants here say it is called a value set. They get paid tons of money to create them so I believe them!

Answer (score 0):

You may think of a variable as containing an element that is a member of a set of numbers.

As such, [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_domain) is a good descriptor for the possible values of this set.

[Range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function) is also often used in a similar context. Here we talk of the range of a function, as the set of values the function can take on. Since a variable always contains the result of some expression or computation, range clearly makes sense too.

Either is appropriate in the proper context.